Weak SSL Cipher Issue: Still Getting B Grade on SSL Labs After Updating nginx.conf and Upgrading nginx
During a VAPT (Vulnerability Assessment and Penetration Testing) of my application, I encountered a weak SSL cipher issue, resulting in a B grade on SSL Labs. Following various recommendations from online resources, I updated my nginx.conf with the following settings:


ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;



Even after upgrading nginx to the latest version (from 1.14.0), the SSL Labs grade remains at B. I'm unsure of what I might be missing. Attached is a screenshot of the current SSL Labs report. Could someone please assist me in identifying and resolving this issue effectively? Thank you.

